# Elm - Dynamic Html Option tags within a Select tag

Tags: elm

Elm newbie here.

When I replace the `CustomerSelect` element within the below `Mpower` module with the following one

```
customers = ["Select Customer","Customer 1","Customer 2","Customer 3"]
customerSelect =
  select [ ]
    [ List.map customerItem customers
    ]
```

I get an Elm Compiler "Type Mismatch" error:

> Function `select` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:
>
> ```
> List VirtualDom.Node
> ```
>
> But it is:
>
> ```
> List (List Html)
> ```

Where does this come from?

```
module Mpower where

import Html exposing (..)
import List exposing (..)

customerItem custname =
  option [ ] [ text custname ]

customerSelect =
  select [ ]
    [
    customerItem "Select Customer",
    customerItem "Customer 1",
    customerItem "Customer 2",
    customerItem "Customer 3"
    ]

view =
  div []
    [ customerSelect
    ]

main =
  view
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List.map` already returns a list, but you still have it in the square brackets, so it's wrapped in another list. Wrap it in parentheses instead:

```
customers = ["Select Customer","Customer 1","Customer 2","Customer 3"]
customerSelect =
  select [ ]
    (List.map customerItem customers)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I had also tried it without the square brackets (to no avail). Is it a correct understanding that enclosing the entire expression in parentheses indicates to the compiler that it is an expression to be evaluated as a second argument of the Select function?

Comment: @Joe yes, that's exactly what the parentheses are for. Otherwise the compiler will think you want to pass a second, third and fourth argument to select